# Add button on top of map fragmet

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I am trying to implement a button on top of my Google Map fragment, but I am unable to see it.

Here is the code (I also tried putting the button outside of the fragment):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.car.MapsActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:text="Demo Button"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

</fragment>
```

Also, here is the java file used in this part:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

**EDIT**: This is the code that initiates the map, maybe it causes the problem:

```
    //this function initializes the map presentation
private void initMap() {
    SupportMapFragment map_fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_map);
    map_fragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            user_map = googleMap;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map is ready!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                getDeviceLocation();

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext()
                        , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                user_map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                user_map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the output that I get (Only shows the map, without the button):
https://prnt.sc/iq5ic3

Comment: Try by writing button tag before fragment tag.

Comment: Tried as well with no success.

Comment: Still doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.user.car.MapsActivity"></fragment>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/map"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="Demo Button" />
```

place the button inside the `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Thank you for posting. Unfortunately, I am still not able to see the buton.

Comment: change the layout height of the fragment to wrap content and try again

Comment: There is something very wierd about this, even if I put the height to 10dp if covers the whole screen...

Comment: try cleaning your project and rebuild its showing correctly in my android studio preview

Comment: Im seeing it as well in my preview, but in my phone it is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Try this. removed some of attribute b'z of that button was hidden.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.user.car.MapsActivity"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Demo Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am able to see the button in the preview: http://prntscr.com/iq5et8. But not on my phone

Comment: Try to clean build and run again. may be that can be caching issue.

Comment: paste screenshot in question or another link. It is blocked for me.

Comment: Same result... Somehow the map overwrites everything except the navigation bar on the top...

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.car.MapsActivity"></fragment>

</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Demo Button" />
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Any idea on what to do?

Comment: @Mr.Code if my answer is work please donot forgot to accept

Comment: I have no idea why it is still not working.... Even if I delete the entire fragment it still shows the map. It has to something with the Java code

Comment: Look at the edit that I have added in the post, maybe its the problem

Comment: @Mr.Code just check once you  inflating correct **xml** or not...`setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);`    I checked you java code it's perfect

Comment: Yes, I checked that as well... No idea whats happening

Comment: @Mr.Code Ok  do one thing bro....just for debug  android:layout_height="100dp" check button is visible or not then let me know.......

Comment: @Mr.Code   or just check FragmentActivity remove replace with AppCompatActivity check once......i donot think this pbm but still check once,,,

Comment: The thing is that if I remove the map fragment it is still showing the map... I have no Idea why

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the navigation bar: here is a picture of the fragment used there: http://prntscr.com/iqm2wy

Comment: Ok did you tried clean and rebuild your code....or better uninstall then reinstall once

Comment: @Yes as you sent that last image there only issues you are occupying full space there only...

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand what you mean